# verification of webstart application fails due to attribute sealed in manifest

Tags: java, manifest, java-web-start, jnlp

I have Java webstart application which uses derbyclient. I sign all jars used by application but when I start it I get warning that application contains both signed and unsigned code and then SecurityException with message 
*class "org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientBaseDataSource$" does not match trust level of other classes in the same package*.

In derbyclient's manifest there is the header *Sealed: true* and there are several packages which are not sealed and are defined like this:

```
Name: org/apache/derby/iapi/services/context/
Sealed: false
```

In java console with trace enabled I can see for every such package message

```
cache: signed entry "org/apache/derby/jdbc/" missing from jar .../derbyclient.jar
```

And this probably causes verification of webstart application to fail because when I remove header *Sealed: true* and sealed packages from manifest of derbyclient manually everything starts working.

Is there a better way to fix the application without modifying derbyclient's manifest?

And if not, is it possible to modify manifest during maven build of the application?